# how to make django dynamic URL works properly with django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

This is my form

```
<form action="{%url 'topicname' %}" method="GET">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search topics" name="searchtopic">
              <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
```

This is my View

```
def searchtopic(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        mysearchtopic = request.GET['searchtopic']

        mydata = myhashtaglist.objects.filter(slug = mysearchtopic)
        context = {
            'mydata':mydata,
            }
    return render(request, 'hzone/result.html',context)
```

This is my result.html page

```
{% for m in mydata %}
<a href="{% url 'topicname' m.slug %}">{{ m.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.apphome, name = 'homepage'),
    path('topic/', views.searchtopic, name = 'topicname'),  
]
```

This is my model

```
class myhashtaglist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 150, null=True, blank = True)
    topicdetails = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
```

what i want is whenever user click on any of the topic on result page this topic should open.
my reult page looks like

```
intro to django
django tutorial 1
django tutorial 2
django tutorial 3
```

but when i am clicking on any of the topic its not taking me to that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need new view and path with a primary key for this purpose.

First of all, start with correcting your result.html

```
{% for m in mydata %}
<a href="{% url 'viewTopic' m.slug %}">{{ m.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Define viewTopic in urls.py

```
 path("topic/<pk>", views.viewTopic, name= "viewTopic")
```

Write viewTopic function in views.py

```
def viewTopic (request, pk):
    topic = myhashtaglist.objects.filter(slug = pk)
    context = { "topic":topic }
    return render (request, "newfile.html", context)
```

And finally, use `{{topic.title}} {{topic.slug}} {{topic.topicdetail}}` in your new html file.

Comment: i am not getting which url should i put in my form action

Comment: You still need topicname url. Don’t change it with what I wrote in answer.  Just add that path in urls.py. And put topicname url in your form action

Comment: now i am getting redirected to the page but not getting data on that page. Intial URL: " http://127.0.0.1:8000/topic/?searchtopic=intro-to-django " when I click on other topics http://127.0.0.1:8000/topic/django-tutorial-1

Comment: You mean you get data on all except “intro to django”? Or you dont get data on anyone? Make sure you write {{topic.topicdetails}}(same for other model objects)  instead of {{topic}}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your `urls.py`. You have one `view` (`searchtopic`) for two different purposes, first you are searching using `def searchtopic(request)` and then using the same function for getting a `result`. You must create a another view for your result something like `def get_result(request, slug)` and then define a url in your `urls.py` after that in your form you can do something like this:

```
{% for m in mydata %}
   <a href="{% url 'your-url-for-resul' m.slug %}">{{ m.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

and the following code will be the second view:

```
def get_result(request, slug):
    result = get_object_or_404(Result, slug=slug)

    return render(request, 'your_template_result.html', {'result': result})
```

Then you must have a `.html` file (here is `your_template_result.html`) to redirect to that page and also unpack your data (here is `result`) inside the same `html` file.

I think this can solve your problem.

Comment: so my first view is going to search in database and second view is displaying the data but how can i call my second view becasue when user clicks on search button only first view is getting called

Comment: @Prakash your second ```view``` will take care of it. Your second view as I mentioned above will take ```slug``` and filter then send back data by redirecting users to a specific result. If you have problem with the second view implementation then I can edit my answer and add the ```view```.

Comment: can you plese ad add the view

Comment: @Prakash here you are.